# Unable to link GLUT

Tags: cmake, glut

I have a CMake file that has the following directive inside:

```
# GLUT
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${OutputExecutable} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES})
```

That seems to be ok as no error is returned. However, later I'm getting the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lglut
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

which is indicating that the linker can't find the glut library's location.

Glut is installed through `brew` and is properly configured with `pkg-config` too.

When I do:

```
pkg-config --libs glut
```

I get:

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/freeglut/3.4.0/lib -lglut
```

When I dig inside the Cmake's cache files, I can see that path being pulled in at various instances.

Any ideas?

I am on OSX Big Sur (11.6.5), Cmake 3.22

I suspect that the problem is that on OSX, I already have GLUT as a Framework inside:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework`

on top of that, I have installed Freeglut through `brew` inside:

`/usr/local/Cellar/freeglut/3.4.0/lib`

So the following:

```
# GLUT
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${OutputExecutable} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES})
```

was finding the brew installed GLUT.

Comment: I think I need to find a way to enforce the Framework GLUT within CMake, and prevent it from finding the brew GLUT?

Comment: `find_package(GLUT)` just **searches** the library. But how do you **link** with that library? [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLUT.html) suggests using either `GLUT::GLUT` target or `GLUT_LIBRARIES` variable. What is your way?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Please see edit(1) for an answer to your question.

Comment: In CMake linking is performed with `target_link_libraries` command. I see no such command in your question post.

Comment: "The problem was resolved." - On Stack Overflow we do NOT post solutions in the **question post** itself. Solutions should be posted in **answer posts**. I expected a person with over 2k reputation to be aware about such policy...

Comment: Yes. I'm aware. Preparing the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the following:

```
# GLUT
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${OutputExecutable} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES})
```

with this:

```
# GLUT
target_link_libraries(${OutputExecutable} "-framework GLUT")
```

This seems to have resolved the problem. So I have to move on. Unfortunately I'm still not sure why the `brew` installed GLUT was failing. But since this has solved my problem, I have to leave it for now.